# React testing component unmount

Tags: testing, reactjs, components

Let's say I have the following scenario to be tested.

After firing close button I want to test if the component is unmounted. So I have:

```
component = ReactUtils.renderIntoDocument(....);
closeButton = ReactUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(component, 'Close-Button');

ReactUtils.Simulate.click(closeButton);

//Assert if component is mounted?
```

Answer (score 0):

[component ismounted](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#ismounted)

> isMounted() returns true if the component is rendered into the DOM, false otherwise.

Comment: yes but there is no isMounted() method on my

    component = ReactUtils.renderIntoDocument(....);